# Facebook app submission issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using '**publish_actions**' & '**manage_pages**' for my Facebook app. I'm trying to submit it for review and just getting same review.[image]

I'm not using pre-populated text.
My screens for app..

[image]
User either manually copy-paste or writes the message...
After entering message and posting screens look like below..

[image]

I'm not sure, what's wrong with the app? Any suggestions?

Comment: You are not supposed to “suggest” what the user should/could post in such a way either. Let them share the link, and let them type whatever message they want while doing so, without any “suggestions”.

Comment: @CBroe: as per Fb policy mentioned in (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill), we can suggest content to user.

Comment: You might want to reach out to app policy folks using the direct support if you have access. or you can post in the facebook developers group , https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers.